# Map access bottleneck in Golang

Tags: data-structures, go, hashmap

I am using Golang to implement naive bayesian classification for a dataset with over 30000 possible tags. I have built the model and I am in the classification phase. I am working on classifying 1000 records and this is taking up to 5 minutes. I have profiled the code with pprof functionality; the top10 are shown below:

```
Total: 28896 samples
   16408  56.8%  56.8%    24129  83.5% runtime.mapaccess1_faststr
    4977  17.2%  74.0%     4977  17.2% runtime.aeshashbody
    2552   8.8%  82.8%     2552   8.8% runtime.memeqbody
    1468   5.1%  87.9%    28112  97.3% main.(*Classifier).calcProbs
     861   3.0%  90.9%      861   3.0% math.Log
     435   1.5%  92.4%      435   1.5% runtime.markspan
     267   0.9%  93.3%      302   1.0% MHeap_AllocLocked
     187   0.6%  94.0%      187   0.6% runtime.aeshashstr
     183   0.6%  94.6%     1137   3.9% runtime.mallocgc
     127   0.4%  95.0%      988   3.4% math.log10
```

Surprisingly the map access seems to be the bottleneck. Has anyone experienced this. What other key, value datastructure can be used to avoid this bottleneck? All the map access is done in the following piece of code given below:

```
func (nb *Classifier) calcProbs(data string) *BoundedPriorityQueue{
    probs := &BoundedPriorityQueue{} 
    heap.Init(probs)

    terms := strings.Split(data, " ")
    for class, prob := range nb.classProb{
        condProb := prob
        clsProbs := nb.model[class]
        for _, term := range terms{
            termProb := clsProbs[term]
            if termProb != 0{
                condProb += math.Log10(termProb)
            }else{
                condProb += -6 //math.Log10(0.000001)
            }
        }
       entry := &Item{
            value: class,
            priority: condProb,
        }
        heap.Push(probs,entry)
    }
    return probs
}
```

The maps are nb.classProb which is `map[string]float64` while the nb.model is a nested map of type

```
map[string]map[string]float64
```

Comment: why are you implementing a naive approach if you know it is as such?

Comment: It would be useful to see actual code, at least to know what kind of key/value are you using. Maps should be rather fast.

Comment: I've gotten crazy fast benchmarks with native maps on strings and ints up to 10M items. As siritinga says, code would be good. What type of map?

Comment: Yes, me too. So I suppose that something is wrong, or the key is huge and computing the hash takes a lot of time.

Comment: Can you provide sample data to test this? I don't get why you push to a priority queue, but the map work seems okay. BTW what Go version and what OS are you using?

Comment: I am using go 1.2 on ubuntu 13.10 running on a vmware virtual machine hosted on mac osx

Comment: I have just benchmarked access time to a map[string]int with 20 characters strings as key, for a map of 30000 elements (I understand it is your case) and access time is about 120 ns per access. In your case your are doing 30 million accesses, and should not take more than a few seconds, but I cannot say what is wrong.

Comment: Could you maybe try running it natively on your mac? It could be some virtualization issue.

Comment: What **would** you expect to be the bottleneck? If your `for _, term := range terms` loops is the main code (inner loop) than it is clear that map lookup will contribute most.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @tomwilde said, another approach that *may* speed up your algorithm is string interning. Namely, you can avoid using a map entirely if you know the domain of keys ahead of time. I wrote a small package that will do [string interning](http://godoc.org/github.com/BurntSushi/intern) for you.

Comment: You need to add a license, pkg.go.dev won't display it right now

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the map access will be the bottleneck in this code: it's the most significant operation inside the two nested loops.

It's not possible to tell for sure from the code that you've included, but I expect you've got a limited number of classes. What you might do, is number them, and store the term-wise class probabilities like this:

```
map[string][NumClasses]float64
```

(ie: for each term, store an array of class-wise probabilities [or perhaps their logs already precomputed], and NumClasses is the number of different classes you have).

Then, iterate over terms first, and classes inside. The expensive map lookup will be done in the outer loop, and the inner loop will be iteration over an array.

This'll reduce the number of map lookups by a factor of NumClasses. This may need more memory if your data is extremely sparse.

The next optimisation is to use multiple goroutines to do the calculations, assuming you've more than one CPU core available.